# Transform a property inside mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I'm developing a set of models, I need to transform the incoming name to canonical link. This is my model

```
import mongo from 'mongoose'

const schema = new mongo.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String, 
        required:  [true, 'El nombre de la marca es necesaria' ],
        unique:    [true, 'Ya existe esta marca'],
        minlength: [3, 'Al menos 3 caracteres'],
        maxlength: [100, 'Máximo 100 caracteres'],
    },
    link: { 
        type: String,
        default: function() {
            return this.name
            .normalize("NFD")
            .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
            .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
            .toLowerCase()
        }
    },
    active: { type: Boolean, default: true }

}, { collection: 'moto-brands' })

export const MotoBrandModel = mongo.model( 'MotoBrand', schema )
```

At this point Typescript show me an error, the server do too.
The error is marked at `this.name`

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'SchemaTypeOpts | Schema |
>   SchemaType'.
>
> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'SchemaTypeOpts'

This could be the simulation

```
Incoming request
{ name: '   El Pingüino maléfico ' }
```

The mongoose model must convert to `el-pinguino-malefico` and set to `link` index as default value.
The function works fine, but what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The documentation said: "Unless it is running on a query with setDefaultsOnInsert, a default function's this refers to the document". So, make sure you are not using setDefaultsOnInsert in the query who is calling the model. (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html)

Comment: Thanks Mauro. My problem is different, I can't insert data to the model, because `this.name` is not working.